# Grouping with linq but leaving out certain items in the result

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following code (you can copy paste and run the code if you have linqpad)

```
   void Main()
    {
        List<data_item> itemlist1= new List<data_item>();
        List<data_item> itemlist2= new List<data_item>();

        itemlist1.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
        {
         id=1,
         LeftHasdata=true 

        })
        ;
        itemlist1.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
        {
         id=2,
         LeftHasdata=false 

        })
        ;

        itemlist2.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
        {
         id=2,

          RightHasData=false 
        })
        ;
        itemlist2.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
        {
         id=1,

          RightHasData=false 
        })
        ;
        itemlist2.Add(new UserQuery.data_item 
        {
         id=3,

          RightHasData=false 
        })
        ;



        //var result= itemlist1.Concat(itemlist2).GroupBy(p=>p.id).Select(s  => new UserQuery.data_item {
        var result= itemlist1.Union(itemlist2).GroupBy(p=>p.id).Select(s  => new UserQuery.data_item {
          id=s.Key,
          LeftHasdata=s.Where(rd=>rd.LeftHasdata!=null).Select(d=>d.LeftHasdata).FirstOrDefault(),
           RightHasData=s.Where(rd=>rd.RightHasData!=null).Select(d=>d.RightHasData).FirstOrDefault(),
           })

           ;
        result.Dump();

    }

// Define other methods and classes here

 public class data_item
 {
     public int id {get;set;}
     public bool? LeftHasdata  { get; set; }
     public bool? RightHasData { get; set; }

}
```

I get the result below:

```
>id LeftHasdata RightHasData 

>1 True False 

>2 False False 

>3 null  False
```

I only want to return results where group has more then one element. This means that the last result row should not be returned. How can i tweak my query to accomplish this.

many thanks in advance

B

Comment: You mean like `.Where(p => p.Count() > 1)`?

Comment: Well, this seems like it. I beleive to have tried to call the "where " extension method but my compiler would not allow it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `Where` clause

```
var result = itemlist1.Union(itemlist2)
                      .GroupBy(p => p.id)
                      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer is filter groups having only one element:

```
itemlist1.Union(itemlist2).GroupBy(p=>p.id).Where(g=>g.Count()==2).Select ...
```

Comment: This also does the job. Thanks